# Jenkins ERROR: Unable to communicate with perforce. No output for: p4 print -q

Tags: jenkins, perforce

The jenkins job was running fine on Mac VM few months back but now it is failing at the beginning itself with error "**ERROR: Unable to communicate with perforce. No output for: p4 print -q** ". I tried rebooting the VM, also checked if the path for p4 is available to the job. CLIENTSPEC is also in place. Everything seems fine but still not able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the P4 server connection from VM's SHELL.

```
p4 -p ssl:ip_address:1666 info

p4 -p ip_address info
```

If you get this msg, you need to re-trust the P4 server from Shell.

******* WARNING P4PORT IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! *******

```
p4 trust -f

p4 info
```